# Can we use logman to catch all events logged into Application channel of event viewer

Tags: windows, logging, etw

I have few processes which logs events in Application channel. I want to catch all events in a time period and store it into etl file. Can we do this using logman.

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation i found that this was not possible using logman. Logman works on provider level not container level of event log. 
We will need to use wevtutil

> wevtutil.exe epl Application C:\temp\ApplicationLog24hours.evtx
>   “/q:*[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000]]]”
>   /ow:true

exports all events in Application event created in a time period of 24 hrs